# Vários itens numa coluna MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para inserir e exibir dados separados em uma única coluna mo MySql?
Ex: Tenho uma coluna (catalogo_endereco), nela quero inserir a rua, a cidade, e o estado numa só coluna e depois poder separar cada um em PHP.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de salvar numa só coluna?

Comment: Evitar de criar muitas colunas, ex: quero colocar o endereço completo, pra utilizar junto e poder pegar apenas a cidade. e Inserir dois números de telefone. To criando um catalogo, então queria evitar criar muitas colunas, vi uma vez no banco de dados do Joomla que utilizam esse método.

Comment: E depois pra fazer uma consulta? As vezes normalização é essencial

Comment: No teu caso eu criaria uma tabela Endereco e depois só passaria o idEndereco pro Catalogo

Comment: Nada o impede de fazer desse modo, porém, a nível profissional é abominável. Caso queira tornar-se um bom profissional, estude normalização e modelagem de dados. Aliás, mesmo a nível amador é recomendável normalizar os dados. Da forma como pretende fazer, independentemente se já viu outros fazendo, vai se tornar um pesadelo futuramente. Talvez não para você mas para o seu cliente e o futuro programador que pegar essa bucha.

Comment: Amigão, isso não é uma boa prática de programação. Não é uma boa ideia usar um campo só.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para armazenar o endereço em uma única coluna e depois extrair as informações você deve garantir que todo e qualquer endereço seja armazenado no mesmo padrão.

Você pode, por exemplo, usar algum tipo de separador (#, $, @) para separar cada campo e depois usar a função `explode`para separar.

Ex.: `Rua das Primas nº 69, Vila Velha, Espirito Santo, Cep.: 29101-000`

Você poderia guardar assim (considerando # como separador):

`Rua das Primas#69#Vila Velha#Espirito Santo##29101000`

Answer (score 13):

**Isso é uma péssima ideia.**

A resposta do @Edgar está correta no sentido em que ela faz o que você quer, mas ela tem vários problemas:

- Se o cidadão colocar um ‘#’ no endereço dele, vai quebrar o seu código.
- No dia que o seu chefe quiser procurar todo mundo que mora em determinada cidade, você não vai ter como fazer isso em SQL — você vai precisar fazer um programa que puxa tudo do banco de dados e faz a busca em PHP; esqueça a possibilidade de usar índices para acelerar a busca.
- No dia que você quiser colocar um campo extra (e.g. bairro) no endereço, você está lascado — todo lugar que acessa esse campo de endereço vai precisar ser alterado pra verificar quantas ‘#’ tem no endereço, ver se é o formato velho ou novo, e adicionar o campo novo se ele ainda não existir.

---

Se você absolutamente insiste em ignorar os conselhos de Maicon, Daniel e meus e dar uma de [padre do balão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelir_Ant%C3%B4nio_de_Carli) e ignorar os gritos de gente que tem mais experiência que você e estudou mais do que você de que “isso vai dar problema”, cogite a possibilidade de pelo menos guardar os dados em JSON:

```
<?php

$endereco = array(
    'rua' => 'Pennsylvania Avenue NW',
    'numero' => '1600',
    'cidade' => 'Washington', 
    'estado' => 'DC',
    'cep' => '20500');

echo json_encode($endereco);
```

Pra recompor o array a partir da string, use `json_decode`. Isso resolve o primeiro e o terceiro (mas não o segundo) problemas que eu mencionei acima.

(Você pode ver isso funcionando no [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/i7Gi2F).)

Comment: Calma aí fera. rs. eu vi um exemplo e pensei que poderia ser a melhor solução. mas já que vi que é uma péssima ideia eu até desisti já. flw.

Comment: +1 pelo "padre do balão". Você é um filósofo grego

Answer (score 0):

O problema que você pode ter em armazenar em uma única coluna é posteriormente para efetuar consultas. 
Vamos dizer que você quer filtrar os registros de uma única cidade. Ficará um pouco mais complexo

Answer (score 0):

Concordo com a observação do Wallace, a resposta do Edgar, é muito insegura. Funcionará até quebrar no primeiro problema. Para inserir os dados, você pode serializar os dados e gravar no banco:

```
$endereco = array(
    'rua' => 'Manuel da Nóbrega',
    'numero' => '32',
    'cidade' => 'São paulo', 
    'estado' => 'SP',
    'cep' => '12345-123');

$endereco_serializado = serialize($endereco);
```

Manda para o banco sua query de inserção:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO TABELA (endereco) VALUES (:endereco)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':endereco'=>$endereco_serializado));
```

E para recuperar:

```
 $sql="SELECT endereco FROM TABELA where id=?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($id);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $endereco = unserialize($result['endereco'])

echo $endereco;
```